# Reference for Jacob Viner research on colonies

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, empirical-evidence

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xeebU8VhmY) video at 6.02 Milton Friedman mentions some 'famous studies' on colonies from Jacob Viner. Does someone know exactly which studies these are?